# Trying to use UIPickerView to make a selection upon which image to display in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

[Using UIPickerView to display different images upon selection in UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309964/using-uipickerview-to-display-different-images-upon-selection-in-uiimageview)

So I was looking at this post to help me perform the same function as this user. I am using a PickerView to have the user select between three different maps and having a ImageView change depending on user selection. I'm running into trouble in the following portion of my code

```
chosenFloor.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[pickerImage objectAtIndex:row]]];
```

It is telling me that 'Incompatible pointer types assigning to UIImage * from UIImageView *

Can someone explain how to convert an UIImage to fit into a UIImageView? I'll include the rest of my code below. I believe I have everything declared appropriately in my .h files which is the problem that the user ran into in the above link.

[Screenshot of my iOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99ZWr.png)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *chooseFloor;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *chosenFloor;
    NSArray *pickerData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *chooseFloor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView        *chosenFloor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerFloor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerImage;
//-(IBAction)performSomeAction:(id)sender;

@end

#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize chooseFloor;
@synthesize pickerFloor;
@synthesize chosenFloor;
@synthesize pickerImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Basement",
                       @"Main Floor",
                       @"Penthouse", nil];

    self.pickerFloor = array;

    self.chooseFloor.dataSource = self;
    self.chooseFloor.delegate = self;

    self.pickerImage = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Basement.png", @"Main.png", @"Penthouse.png", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    //Determine how many columns in my pickerView
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    //Determine the number of rows in my pickerView
    return [pickerFloor count];
}

//Delegate Method
//This delegate method gives us s way to retrieve the selected item from the picker view
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerFloor objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    chosenFloor.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[pickerImage objectAtIndex:row]]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong at this line:

```
 chosenFloor.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[pickerImage objectAtIndex:row]]];
```

`chosenFloor.image` is a `UIImage`. It should be

```
chosenFloor.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[pickerImage objectAtIndex:row]];
```